# Run test runner at project level and export results to different folders based on testsuite

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have an Data drive soapui automation project. The project has 4 seperate testsuites in it. I want to run all 4 test suites at once. When i run testrunner at project level, i can only set one result folder.

The problem i have with that is results from different test suites get mixed up . Can i have results from seperate test suites into seperate test result folders though i am running them all at once from project level

Comment: What is your use case? is there any file name pattern for the files to identify if it belongs to a certain suite?

Comment: Results from test runner have request and response xml and the file name also has test suite name in the file name. I would like to divide these xml results into separate sub folders in the main folder